# Autolayout UIScrollView not scrolling (in landscape)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am starting to lose my mind over this. Everything I try seems to make me fail to let a scrollview scroll properly.

I am making a application to show a TCG card with some info gathered from a REST API, which for now looks like this (the other views are removed for testing purposes):

[image]

Because of the image height, the TextView and Label will fall off in landscape mode, and it should be scrollable.

This is my current structure (without constraints), based on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnQsFlMGDsI) video:

[image]

I have tried for literally hours to fiddle around with the constraints to get it work, but every time *something* breaks. Sometimes you get the awesome 'Scrollable Content Size Ambiguity' error, and if that is fixed, views get the 'Misplaced Views' error.

I have a feeling this should not be so hard to achieve, though I can't seem to get there. Can someone point me to a *correct* resource, because finding one seems impossible.

Edit: To describe a little more what I have right now is everything have a constraint to the view above itself and the last one (TextView) also has a constraint to the bottom of the container.

Comment: Try resetting using the `Reset to suggested constraints` button for your whole view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking out the 'View' and just having the content directly in the 'Scroll View'.

[image]

Comment: I used it without the view before, but the TextFields in there couldn't detect the width and got really small (minimal size). I'll try with these constraints, thanks! I'll report back when I get a chance to try it.

Comment: Yes, I faced the same issue with the constraints on the TextField. I just wrapped the Label and TextField in a View so it didn't shrink.

Comment: That is what I done with the whole content, not just a footer. Works right now, though the view (content view) has tot have a height specified. Thanks!